# Can't load custom pylint module

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pylint

I am following a simple tutorial that creates a [custom checker/module](http://atodorov.org/blog/2018/01/05/how-to-write-pylint-checker-plugins/) for Pylint. The code looks like this.

**bad_code.py**

```
def func():
    print("Bad code")

    return
```

**useless_return.py** (This is the checker)

```
import astroid

from pylint import checkers
from pylint import interfaces
from pylint.checkers import utils


class UselessReturnChecker(checkers.BaseChecker):
    __implements__ = interfaces.IAstroidChecker

    name = 'useless-return'

    msgs = {
        'R2119': ("Useless return at end of function or method",
                  'useless-return',
                  'Emitted when a bare return statement is found at the end of '
                  'function or method definition'
                  ),
        }

    @utils.check_messages('useless-return')
    def visit_functiondef(self, node):
        """
            Checks for presence of return statement at the end of a function
            "return" or "return None" are useless because None is the default
            return type if they are missing
        """
        # if the function has empty body then return
        if not node.body:
            return

        last = node.body[-1]
        if isinstance(last, astroid.Return):
            # e.g. "return"
            if last.value is None:
                self.add_message('useless-return', node=node)
            # e.g. "return None"
            elif isinstance(last.value, astroid.Const) and (last.value.value is None):
                self.add_message('useless-return', node=node)


def register(linter):
    """required method to auto register this checker"""
    linter.register_checker(UselessReturnChecker(linter))
```

Note that both files are in the project root.

Then I executed the following command to test it.
`$ pylint --load-plugins=useless_return bad_code.py`

It throws errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/my/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/lint/pylinter.py", line 609, in load_plugin_configuration
    module = astroid.modutils.load_module_from_name(modname)
  File "path/to/my/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/astroid/modutils.py", line 228, in load_module_from_name
    return importlib.import_module(dotted_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'useless_return'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/my/project/venv/bin/pylint", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run_pylint())
  File "path/to/my/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/__init__.py", line 24, in run_pylint
    PylintRun(sys.argv[1:])
  File "path/to/my/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/lint/run.py", line 383, in __init__
    linter.load_plugin_configuration()
  File "path/to/my/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/lint/pylinter.py", line 613, in load_plugin_configuration
    self.add_message("bad-plugin-value", args=(modname, e), line=0)
  File "path/to/my/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/lint/pylinter.py", line 1519, in add_message
    self._add_one_message(
  File "path/to/my/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/lint/pylinter.py", line 1456, in _add_one_message
    self.stats.increase_single_module_message_count(self.current_name, msg_cat, 1)
  File "path/to/my/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pylint/utils/linterstats.py", line 296, in increase_single_module_message_count
    self.by_module[modname][type_name] += increase
KeyError: None
```

Note that I don't have `pylint` installed globally, only in my `venv`.

The command `which pylint` returns `path/to/my/project/venv/bin/pylint`.

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't confirm this is the best way to test a custom checker. But the only way that I found is to copy the custom module into `pylint/checkers` and run the command. To test only the custom checker

`$pylint --load-plugins=useless_return --disable=all --enable=useless-return bad_code.py`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Discussion with Pylint maintainers going very well, it seems like a really responsive project. The recommendation from them is definitely to install your custom checker as part of a module, like any other library you might install with `pip`. Expect to see some changes around this to bring more clarity soon!

---

I had a similar problem, and I think I've identified the root cause. I've opened an issue with pylint: [PyCQA/pylint#7264](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/7264)

TL;DR when you specify the module using the command line, it tries to load and register it **without** the current directory added to the sys path (even if your init-hook does this), so cannot find the file to import.

### Workarounds

Until such time as there is a fix, or this is called out in documentation, you have a couple of options:

- As OP found, putting the module in pylints checkers directory does solve this. You can put it in any sys.path directory other than the current working dir. EDIT: pylint maintainers recommend installing your custom checker into your site packages as its own package.
- Do not use the command line argument for `--load_plugins`, instead use a pylintrc file, in the same directory as your code, that specifies at least the following two things:

  ```
  [MASTER]
  # Python code to execute, usually for sys.path manipulation such as
  # pygtk.require().
  init-hook="from pylint.config import find_pylintrc; import sys; sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(find_pylintrc()))"

  # List of plugins (as comma separated values of python module names) to load,
  # usually to register additional checkers.
  load-plugins=your_custom_checker
  ```